# Extract tables in PDF that are split into several pages into excel

Tags: python, excel, pdf, extract, python-camelot

I have a PDF and there is a table split into several pages (link below). I am trying to extract the data in the table and save it in an excel workbook.

I have tried to use Camelot and it managed to extract the table correctly in Page 1 but the alignment is off from Page 2 onwards (it took the 2 columns of the 2nd page and placed it on the first two columns instead of it being on the 6th and 7th column).

I would appreciate the help!

Link to PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14QHlerYZ_cq-vO9m-zMbEZP1ntSvTZ40/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please add you code here

Comment: Sure, here:

import camelot as cam

pdf = cam.read_pdf("200403-clusters.pdf", pages = 'all', flavor = 'stream')
print (pdf[0].df)
print (pdf[1].df)